# How to update each dictionary key value in the below list python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I  am creating a dictionary inside the python list.

```
>>> my_dict=[dict()]*2 
>>> my_dict[0]['name']='TAMIL'
>>> my_dict[0]
{'name': 'TAMIL'}
>>> my_dict
[{'name': 'TAMIL'}, {'name': 'TAMIL'}]
```

it updates the `my_dict[1]['name']` with the  same value of `my_dict[0]['name']` how to avoid this ,In my case I want 
access and update only each dictionary key.

Answer (score 1):

You are creating two *references* to the same object not two different objects, use range to actually create `n` different dicts:

```
my_dict=[{} for _ in range(2)]
```

As I mentioned already `my_dict=[dict()]*2` creates to reference to the same object so  `my_dict[0] is my_dict[1]`.

```
n [2]: my_dict = [dict()] * 2  
In [3]: id(my_dict[0])
Out[3]: 140220584402056

In [4]: id(my_dict[1]) # same id, same object
Out[4]: 140220584402056

In [5]: my_dict=[{} for _ in range(2)]

In [6]: id(my_dict[0]) 
Out[6]: 140220898678728

In [7]: id(my_dict[1]) # different id, different object
Out[7]: 140220579542088
```

Comment: lol two downvotes with no comment.

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with this. +1 from me. Maybe use `xrange` in python 2, but for 2 elements it probably doesn't matter.

Comment: thank you Padraic for let me knowing the mistake,i replaced with range and it works now

Comment: @juanchopanza, true, I did not know if the OP were using 2 or 3 so I went with the safest option.

Comment: I must say I find the voting patterns in this tag most perplexing.

Comment: @tamil, no worries, outside of numpy where views and arrays have different ids but in fact reference the same data usually when id's are different you have different objects in memory, when they are equal you have the same object.

Answer (score -1):

You better do it like this: 
my_dict[0]= {'name':'Tamil'}

This only updates the first element in the dictionary. The otherone will be empty.

EDIT**

The above answer adresses an important thing I did not know about. So definitely the better answer. I gave this one, because it does seem to solve your problem:

```
>>> my_dict=[dict()]*2
>>> my_dict
[{}, {}]
>>> my_dict[0]= {'name':'Tamil'}
>>> my_dict
[{'name': 'Tamil'}, {}]
```